# How to create a function using a Typedef Struct to return an array of split strings

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, strtok

I am stuck with memory allocation while solving the exercise. Objective of this exercise is to create a function that takes two arguments (e.g. "abc def gh-!" && "-") by splitting the string of characters by the separator which in this case is the second argument and then return an array that is in my typedef struct which contains the new split strings.

Here is my code so far...

```
    #ifndef STRUCT_STRING_ARRAY
#define STRUCT_STRING_ARRAY
typedef struct s_string_array
{
    int size;
    char** array;
} string_array;
#endif

string_array* my_split(char* str, char* sep) {

  string_array*ptr=(string_array*)malloc(sizeof(string_array)); //Memory allocation Struct

  int i;
  int j;
  int words;
  int in_word;

  i = 0;
  words = 1;

  while (str[i]) {
      if (str[i] != *sep) {
          if (!in_word) {
              words++; // Count number of words inside the string
          }
          in_word = 1;
      } else {
          in_word = 0;
      }
      i++;
  }
  ptr->size = words;
  ptr->array=malloc(sizeof(char*)*ptr->size); // Allocate the array of pointer inside struct

  int size = 0;
  i = 0;
  j = 0;
  while (i < ptr->size)  {
      while (str[j] != *sep) {
          size++;
          j++;
      }
      ptr->array[i]=malloc(sizeof(char) * (size + 1));
      ptr->array[i][size+1] = '\0';
    i++;
  }

  int c = 0;
  int r = 0;
  i = 1;
  j = 0;

  while (i < ptr->size) {
      if (str[j] != *sep) {
          while (str[j] != *sep) {
              ptr->array[c][r++] = str[j++];
          }
      }
      i++;
      c++;
  }
  printf("%s\n", ptr->array[0]);
  printf("Words in new Array is: %d\n", ptr->size);
  printf("J is at index: %d\n", j);
  printf("The character at index J is: %c\n", str[j]);
  printf("The first index of the array is now at: %d\n", c);
}

int main() {
    my_split("abc def gh-!", "-");
    return 0;
}
```

The Return Value must be: ["abc def gh", "!"]

Please help.

Comment: `ptr->array[i]=malloc(sizeof(char) * (size + 1)); ptr->array[i][size+1] = '\0';` Oops, out-of-range write!

Comment: Is the separarator a char pointer because it may contain more than one spearator? Is separator the string. (for example "--"). Otherwise I do not see any reson it to be a `char *` and probably your code (abstracting from errors) is too simple.

Comment: The separator is a unique character represented as a string so (for example "-", " ", "d")

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```c
#include <stdbool.h> /* for bool data type */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE 8

typedef struct split_result {
    size_t length;
    char **tokens;
} splitted;

struct split_result split(char *target_str, char *delimiters) {
    struct split_result ret = {0, NULL};
    size_t buffer_size = DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE;
    size_t temp;

    ret.tokens = (char **)calloc(buffer_size, sizeof(char *));

    if (!ret.tokens)
        return ret;

    while (true) {
        target_str += strspn(target_str, delimiters);
        temp = strcspn(target_str, delimiters);

        if (!temp)
            break;

        if (temp) {
            if (ret.length >= buffer_size) {
                buffer_size += DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE;
                ret.tokens = (char **)realloc(ret.tokens, buffer_size * sizeof(char *));

                if (!ret.tokens)
                    return ret;
            }

            ret.tokens[ret.length] = (char *)malloc(temp + 1);

            if (!ret.tokens[ret.length])
                return ret;

            strncpy(ret.tokens[ret.length], target_str, temp);
            ret.tokens[ret.length][temp] = 0;
            ret.length++;
            target_str += temp;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

void * free_split(struct split_result *destroy) {
    size_t index = 0;

    while (destroy->tokens[index]) {
        free(destroy->tokens[index]);
        destroy->tokens[index] = NULL;
        index++;
    }

    free(destroy->tokens);
    destroy->tokens = NULL;
    destroy->length = 0;

    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    char *text = strdup("foo.bar");
    char *del = strdup(".");
    struct split_result res = split(text, del);

    printf("length: %ld\n", res.length);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        printf("token: %s\n", res.tokens[i]);
    }

    free_split(&res);
    printf("main=%s\n", text);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).